# Unable to view logs for yarn-resource-manager

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, analytics-for-apache-hdp

I tried with various command and I still do have issues in viewing the yarn logs and here are the steps that I followed to view logs

```
[root@iop-rm1 /]# yarn application -list

17/04/03 13:15:21 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at iop-rm1.qatc/172.18.0.4:8032

Total number of applications (application-types: [] and states: [SUBMITTED, ACCEPTED, RUNNING]):1

            Application-Id      Application-Name        Application-Type          User       Queue               State         Final-State         Progress                        Tracking-URL
  application_1491225022815_0002      paxi                 SPARK                 paxata     default              ACCEPTED         UNDEFINED              0%                                 N/A
```

When I view the yarn logs it displays as

```
[root@iop-rm1 /]# yarn logs -applicationId application_1491222823231_0001

17/04/03 12:48:57 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at iop-rm1.qatc/172.18.0.4:8032

/tmp/logs/root/logs/application_1491222823231_0001 does not exist.

Log aggregation has not completed or is not enabled.
```

I also enabled the Log aggregation in the `core-site.xml` file

```
<name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>

<value>true</value>
```

I created the path for logs which does not exist but i am not able to see yarn logs

Is there any possible way of viewing the yarn logs ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot view the **aggregated** logs of an YARN application which is not yet **`FINISHED`**.

From the [description](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) of `yarn.log-aggregation-enable` property:

> Log aggregation collects each container's logs and moves these logs
>   onto the directory configured in `yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir`
>   only **after the completion** of the application.

You can try the same command `yarn logs -applicationId <application ID>` to view the logs once the application has completed.

To view the logs while the job is **`RUNNING`**, use the ResourceManger Web Interface. It will be available in `http://ResourceManager_IP_Address:8088/`.

**PS:** You should add the property for log aggregation in `yarn-site.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to restart your cluster in order to make the log aggregation enabled.